# php notice undefined index session

Tags: php, session, indexing, undefined, notice

i have PHP Notice:  Undefined index: langid in the error logs 
and here is the code it's defined so any idea about what is wrong with my code

```
<?php 

if(($_SESSION['langid'])!="" ){

    $langid=$_SESSION['langid'];
    $_SESSION['langid']=$langid;


    if(isset($_REQUEST['langid']) && $_REQUEST['langid']!="" ){
        $langid=$_REQUEST['langid'];
        $_SESSION['langid']=$langid;
    }else{

    }

}else{
$langid=1;
$_SESSION['langid']=$langid;



if(isset($_REQUEST['langid']) && $_REQUEST['langid']!="" ){
    $langid=$_REQUEST['langid'];
    $_SESSION['langid']=$langid;
}else{

}
}
```

Comment: Add first line as `session_start();` might solve your problem.

Comment: Why are you doing this `$langid=$_SESSION['langid'];$_SESSION['langid']=$langid;`??

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<?php

if ( isset($_SESSION['langid']) )
{

    $langid=$_SESSION['langid'];
    $_SESSION['langid']=$langid;


    if(isset($_REQUEST['langid']) && $_REQUEST['langid']!="" ){
        $langid=$_REQUEST['langid'];
        $_SESSION['langid']=$langid;
    }else{

    }

}else{
$langid=1;
$_SESSION['langid']=$langid;



if(isset($_REQUEST['langid']) && $_REQUEST['langid']!="" ){
    $langid=$_REQUEST['langid'];
    $_SESSION['langid']=$langid;
}else{

}
}

?>
```

And you will will have no notices about warnings .but the code is no sense :

```
$langid=$_SESSION['langid'];
$_SESSION['langid']=$langid;
```

has no sense